# How to remove console errors from iframe in react.js page

Tags: reactjs, iframe, error-handling, console.log

how are you.
I have added iframe to my react.js page and it works but I got so many errors from iframe.
This is iframe component I made to avoid console error, but not working

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from 'react'

export default function (props) {
    let iframeRef = useRef(null)
    useEffect(() => {
        const iframecurrent = iframeRef.current
        iframecurrent.contentWindow.console.log = function() { /* nop */ };
    }, [])
    return <iframe {...props} ref={iframeRef} />
}
```

Is there any solution for this issue?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

May be silly answer but have you tried overriding the `console.error` method instead of `console.log`

```
useEffect(() => {
        const iframecurrent = iframeRef.current
        iframecurrent.contentWindow.console.error = function() { /* nop */ };
}, [])
```